# Spring Batch Partitioning - reuse of JMS Channels?

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-integration

I am writing a Spring Batch job that is composed of 4 independent steps and would like to distribute the work over the nodes of the cluster. I was thinking about using a flow to break the job into 4 jobs that execute in parallel. Each of the 4 jobs would be configured to run as a single partition. It appears to work (not fully tested in a cluster) but requires a definition of separate PartitionHandlers, Request and Response Channels, and Outbound Gateway.

Can any of these entities be reused across partitioned steps?

Any other suggested approaches ?

Answer (score 0):

For parallel processing, I can advice [this doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/scalability.html)

Ex:

```
<job id="parallelJobExample">
    <split id="parallelProcessingExample" task-executor="taskExecutor">
        <flow>
            <step id="step1" parent="independetJob1"/>
        </flow>
        <flow>
            <step id="step2" parent="independetJob2"/>
        </flow>
    </split>
</job>

<step id="independetJob1">
    <tasklet>
        <chunk reader="parallelReader1" processor="parallelProcessor1" writer="parallelWriter1" commit-interval="1000"/>
    </tasklet>
</step>

<step id="independetJob2">
    <tasklet>
        <chunk reader="parallelReader2" processor="parallelProcessor2" writer="parallelWriter2" commit-interval="1000"/>
    </tasklet>
</step>
```

İf you need jms example, I could also provide.